# Является ли тип числовым?

Tags: c#

Как проверить, является ли тип числовым?

```
public static bool IsNumeric(this Type type)
{ 
   ...        
}
```

Интересно решение как для встроенных типов, так и для сторонних/своих.

Comment: А что такое _числовой тип_, с учетом обобщения на не встроенные? Есть какое-то _определение_ / _требования_?

Comment: *Числовые типы - это типы, предназначенные для хранения чисел. Когда вы выполняете математические операции, вы имеете дело с числовыми значениями.* [источник цитаты](http://sernam.ru/book_java.php?id=4)

Comment: Цитата так себе. Давайте отбросим _примитивные_ типы. Арифметические операции могут быть определены для самых разных типов. Например для `Nullable<T>`: `(int?)1 + (int?)2`. Равно как и для _составных_ типов: комплексные числа, вектора и т.д.. Число можно хранить и в единственном поле в виде массива байт. Такой тип будет _числовым_? Быть может, примеры практического использования метода `IsNumeric` прольют свет на смысл этого загадочного термина... ;)

Comment: а может лучше отбросим софистику )) ? сходите по ссылке из ответа - почему-то там никто не спросил что такое Numeric Type..

Comment: Это не софистика. Если вы хотите получить _хороший_ ответ на свой вопрос (в вашем случае - избавиться от недостатков подхода в ответе), нужно сформулировать вопрос так, чтобы это стало возможным. По указанной ссылке речь не шла о _пользовательских_ типах, только о _примитивных_. В противном случае, я убежден, вопрос об определении не заставил бы себя долго ждать. Так как вы используете метод `IsNumeric`? Быть может, вас интересует лишь определены ли у типа арифметические операторы?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь заставить меня сформулировать то, что и будет наполовину ответом. Я не готов этого сделать. Посмотрите ещё раз на ответ ниже, вот эти типы -- числовые. Был бы какой-нибудь fixed point  в коробке .Net - тоже числовой. BigInteger - тоже числовой.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47760/discussion-between-4per-and-dmitry-d).

Answer (score 2):

Решение по мотивам https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749966/c-sharp-how-to-determine-whether-a-type-is-a-number

```
public static bool IsNumeric(this Type type)
{
    HashSet<Type> NumericTypes = new HashSet<Type>
    {  
        //встроенные:
        typeof(Byte),
        typeof(SByte),
        typeof(UInt16),
        typeof(UInt32),
        typeof(UInt64),
        typeof(Int16),
        typeof(Int32),
        typeof(Int64),
        typeof(Decimal),
        typeof(Double),
        typeof(Single),

        //сторонние:
        typeof(Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleDecimal)
    };
    return NumericTypes.Contains(type);
}
```

Недостатки:

- нужно дописывать каждый новый тип в код, вероятно в ходе лечения очередного бага

Comment: Вынесите определение NumericTypes из метода.

Answer (score 2):

### Определения

Поскольку постановка задачи включает и пользовательские типы, определим *числовой* тип следующим образом:

> Типы, реализующие арифметические операторы `+`, `-` (бинарный), `-` (унарный), `/`, `*`, называются *числовыми*.

Заодно определим и *целочисленные* типы так:

> Типы, реализующие битовые операторы `&`, `|`, `^`, `~`, называются *целочисленными*.

*Если необходимо, нет никаких препятствий для расширения списка операторов в любом из указанных определений.*

---

### Реализация

Для решения данной задачи может помочь следующий класс, основанный на библиотеке [MiscUtils](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) и использующий `Linq.Expressions`:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

/// <summary>
/// Provides easy access to the standard operators (addition, etc) 
/// for generic types, using type inference to simplify usage.
/// </summary>
public static class Numeric<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates that the <typeparamref name="T"/> type has the arithmetic operators.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly bool IsNumeric;

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates that the <typeparamref name="T"/> type has the bitwise arithmetic operators.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly bool IsInteger;

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a function delegate representing a unary operation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TArg1">The parameter type.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TResult">The return type.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="body">Body factory.</param>
    /// <param name="indicator">The <c>false</c> is set in this <c>bool</c> variable if there is no such operator.</param>
    /// <returns>Compiled function delegate.</returns>
    private static Func<TArg1, TResult> CreateExpression<TArg1, TResult>(
        Func<Expression, UnaryExpression> body, ref bool indicator)
    {
        ParameterExpression inp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TArg1), "inp");
        try
        {
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<TArg1, TResult>>(body(inp), inp).Compile();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            indicator = false;
            string msg = ex.Message; // avoid capture of ex itself
            return delegate { throw new InvalidOperationException(msg); };
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a function delegate representing a binary operation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TArg1">The first parameter type.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TArg2">The second parameter type.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TResult">The return type.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="body">Body factory.</param>
    /// <param name="indicator">The <c>false</c> is set in this <c>bool</c> variable if there is no such operator.</param>
    /// <returns>Compiled function delegate.</returns>
    private static Func<TArg1, TArg2, TResult> CreateExpression<TArg1, TArg2, TResult>(
        Func<Expression, Expression, BinaryExpression> body, ref bool indicator)
    {
        return CreateExpression<TArg1, TArg2, TResult>(body, false, ref indicator);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a function delegate representing a binary operation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="castArgsToResultOnFailure">
    /// If no matching operation is possible, attempt to convert
    /// TArg1 and TArg2 to TResult for a match? For example, there is no
    /// "decimal operator /(decimal, int)", but by converting TArg2 (int) to
    /// TResult (decimal) a match is found.
    /// </param>
    /// <typeparam name="TArg1">The first parameter type.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TArg2">The second parameter type.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TResult">The return type.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="body">Body factory.</param>
    /// <param name="indicator">The <c>false</c> is set in this <c>bool</c> variable if there is no such operator.</param>
    /// <returns>Compiled function delegate.</returns>
    private static Func<TArg1, TArg2, TResult> CreateExpression<TArg1, TArg2, TResult>(
        Func<Expression, Expression, BinaryExpression> body, bool castArgsToResultOnFailure, ref bool indicator)
    {
        ParameterExpression lhs = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TArg1), "lhs");
        ParameterExpression rhs = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TArg2), "rhs");
        try
        {
            try
            {
                return Expression.Lambda<Func<TArg1, TArg2, TResult>>(body(lhs, rhs), lhs, rhs).Compile();
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {
                if (castArgsToResultOnFailure && !(         // if we show retry                                                        
                        typeof(TArg1) == typeof(TResult) &&  // and the args aren't
                        typeof(TArg2) == typeof(TResult)))
                { // already "TValue, TValue, TValue"...
                    // convert both lhs and rhs to TResult (as appropriate)
                    Expression castLhs = typeof(TArg1) == typeof(TResult) ?
                            (Expression)lhs :
                            Expression.Convert(lhs, typeof(TResult));
                    Expression castRhs = typeof(TArg2) == typeof(TResult) ?
                            (Expression)rhs :
                            Expression.Convert(rhs, typeof(TResult));

                    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TArg1, TArg2, TResult>>(
                        body(castLhs, castRhs), lhs, rhs).Compile();
                }
                throw;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            indicator = false;
            string msg = ex.Message; // avoid capture of ex itself
            return delegate { throw new InvalidOperationException(msg); };
        }
    }

    public static readonly T Zero;

    public static readonly Func<T, T, T> Add;
    public static readonly Func<T, T, T> Sub;
    public static readonly Func<T, T, T> Mul;
    public static readonly Func<T, T, T> Div;
    public static readonly Func<T, T> Neg;

    public static readonly Func<T, T, T> Or;
    public static readonly Func<T, T, T> And;
    public static readonly Func<T, T, T> Xor;
    public static readonly Func<T, T> Not;


    static Numeric()
    {
        IsNumeric = true;
        Add = CreateExpression<T, T, T>(Expression.Add, ref IsNumeric);
        Sub = CreateExpression<T, T, T>(Expression.Subtract, ref IsNumeric);
        Mul = CreateExpression<T, T, T>(Expression.Multiply, ref IsNumeric);
        Div = CreateExpression<T, T, T>(Expression.Divide, ref IsNumeric);
        Neg = CreateExpression<T, T>(Expression.Negate, ref IsNumeric);

        IsInteger = true;
        And = CreateExpression<T, T, T>(Expression.And, ref IsInteger);
        Or = CreateExpression<T, T, T>(Expression.Or, ref IsInteger);
        Not = CreateExpression<T, T>(Expression.Not, ref IsInteger);
        Xor = CreateExpression<T, T, T>(Expression.ExclusiveOr, ref IsInteger);


        Type typeT = typeof(T);
        if (typeT.IsValueType && typeT.IsGenericType && typeT.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
        {
            // get the *inner* zero (not a null Nullable<TValue>, but default(TValue))
            Type nullType = typeT.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            Zero = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(nullType);
        }
        else if (typeT.IsValueType)
        {
            Zero = default(T);
        }
        else
        {
            Zero = typeT == typeof(string)
                ? (T)(object)String.Empty
                : (T)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeT);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calculate the squared specified value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x">The value.</param>
    /// <returns>The squared value.</returns>
    public static T Pow2(T x)
    {
        return Mul(x, x);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raise the specified value to the 3rd power.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x">The value.</param>
    /// <returns>Value raised to the 3rd power.</returns>
    public static T Pow3(T x)
    {
        return Mul(Mul(x, x), x);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raise the specified value to the Nth power.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x">The value.</param>
    /// <param name="n">The power.</param>
    /// <returns>Value raised to the Nth power.</returns>
    public static T Pow(T x, int n)
    {
        if (n <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(n));

        T prod = x;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            prod = Mul(prod, x);
        return prod;
    }
}
```

Пример использования:

```
Console.WriteLine(Numeric<int>.IsNumeric); // true
Console.WriteLine(Numeric<int>.IsInteger); // true

Console.WriteLine(Numeric<float>.IsNumeric); // true
Console.WriteLine(Numeric<float>.IsInteger); // false

Console.WriteLine(Numeric<string>.IsNumeric); // false
Console.WriteLine(Numeric<string>.IsInteger); // false
```

Пример для пользовательского типа:

```
internal sealed class A
{
    public readonly int Value;

    public A(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public static A operator +(A a, A b)
    {
        return new A(a.Value + b.Value);
    }

    public static A operator -(A a, A b)
    {
        return new A(a.Value - b.Value);
    }

    public static A operator *(A a, A b)
    {
        return new A(a.Value * b.Value);
    }

    public static A operator /(A a, A b)
    {
        return new A(a.Value / b.Value);
    }

    public static A operator -(A a)
    {
        return new A(-a.Value);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Выдача:

```
Console.WriteLine(Numeric<A>.IsNumeric); // true
Console.WriteLine(Numeric<A>.IsInteger); // false
```

---

### Побочный эффект

Вообще, данный класс задумывался как средство использования арифметики для обобщенных (generic) типов. В рамках же текущей задачи это является приятным побочным эффектом. К примеру, возьмем такой класс:

```
internal sealed class MyVector<T>
{
    private readonly List<T> values;
    public readonly ReadOnlyCollection<T> Values;

    public MyVector(params T[] collection)
    {
        if (!Numeric<T>.IsNumeric)
            throw new NotSupportedException($"The type {typeof(T).FullName} must be numeric");

        values = new List<T>(collection);
        Values = new ReadOnlyCollection<T>(values);
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        values.Add(item);
    }

    public T Sum => values.Aggregate(Numeric<T>.Zero, Numeric<T>.Add);
    public T SumPow2 => values.Select(Numeric<T>.Pow2).Aggregate(Numeric<T>.Zero, Numeric<T>.Add);
}
```

Обратите внимание на свойства `Sum` и `SumPow2`. Если тип `T` - *числовой*, то в этих свойствах будет вычисляться соответственно сумма и сумма квадратов всех элементов для любого `T`.